# JPEG scans to one PDF with Ruby using Prawn

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, prawn

I have a bunch of JPEGs, which are scans of the ~ same size:

- image1: 4816 × 6900
- image2: 4816 × 6900
- image3: 4816 × 6848 (tried to make it the same size as other - the image is still broken in export)

I convert them using ImageMagick to PDF using this command:

```
$ convert image1.jpg image2.jpg image3.jpg output.pdf
```

Output file is rather odd - images of the same size are exported fine, while `image3`, which has less height (6848), appears to be exported to the page ~10 times smaller compared to other pages.

[image]

So I decided to use Prawn to do the same:

```
Prawn::Document.generate(pdf_path, page_size: 'EXECUTIVE') do
  images.each do |image|
    # `image` is a service object wrapping image parameters & path to it
    start_new_page(size: image,size, layout: :portrait)
    image image_path, at: [0, 0], width: image.width, height: image.height
  end
end
```

In the end I get PDF with N empty pages (no images). But according to the PDF size, it contains those image (I suppose), I've just aligned it wrong.

Can't get an idea how to fix that. Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post links to your 3 input images. Also please identify what version of ImageMagick you used and on what platform/OS. You could try to pad all of your JPGs to the same size and then convert to PDF using Image magick. You should check the density and units of the 3 input jpg to be sure they are the same density. That might be what is causing the issue.

Comment: Yay, it was a density problem (partially), so even 3 images had the same resolution, they have different density (72x72 and 600x600) (`identify -format "%x x %y" image.jpg). I can't post original images though, its under NDA, but your point was helpful!